# How does my Xamarin.Android app know which size layout to use?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

After reading through Android's guide on supporting multiple screen sizes I now know that I need to create multiple layouts for each screen size in order to make sure the elements are located where I want them.

One thing the guide didn't mention is how to programmatically specify in my Activities which layout will get loaded. Is this because Android will automatically detect which layout to use based on the name of the folder it's located in? For example, a layout in a folder named "layout-sw700dp" will be selected for devices with that screen width?

In-short, I want to know if utilizing alternate layouts for different screen sizes is simply a matter of placing the different layouts in the appropriately named and located folders. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2WId.png) a picture of the layout in Xamarin Studio with the properties pane displayed. It looks the way I want it on Nexus 4; everything centered. But when I switch to a different-sized device, the elements are no longer centered. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lya54.png).

Comment: Yes it is.  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: If you use `dp` for all your layouts, then the elements will scale according to screen density. The only reason you should use alternative layouts is if you wanted a tablet or a landscape oriented device to display "wider" content for example.

Comment: I've used dp for the padding on all my layouts but the elements still appear in different locations on different screen sized.

Answer (score 0):

As cricket_007 sad, you should use diferent xmls when using diferent orientations or making your app more tablet friendly.

When it comes to phone you should practise creating one xml that will cover large range of phones.

And dont use padding for placing elements on screan. For example, dont use pading to set TextView on right side of screan. If you use it lite that and set paddingLeft=250dp on some scren your textView will be placed on right edge but on tablet it will be around center.

Proper way is to set something about this:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:padding="10dp"/>
```

an this must be in RelativeLayout to be affective. This textView will be positioned on every phone and tablet on the right side of screen with small padding.

Comment: How should I position my elements without using padding? Is there another way to get them where I want?

Comment: You can post image what you want to achieve or explain so we can explain how does layouts and views work.

Comment: Updated with images